# REmixJS and Prisma converting from TypeScript to Rew Javascript for instance of Prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma, remix

I am trying to work with RemixJS and Prisma but not using type script. I would like to create a instance of Prisma for development. How can I convert this declare global to simple JS? I am very new to Prisma and RemixJS

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
let db: PrismaClient;

declare global {
  var __db__: PrismaClient | undefined;
}


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   db = new PrismaClient();
} else {
   if (!global.__db__) {
   global.__db__ = new PrismaClient();
}
   db = global.__db__;
   db.$connect();
}

export { db };
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is plain JS, just remove `declare global` and `: PrismaClient`, as those are TS type declarations.

Also, you have one too many closing brackets for your `else` statement

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
let db

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   db = new PrismaClient();
} else {
   if (!global.__db__) {
   global.__db__ = new PrismaClient();
   db = global.__db__;
   db.$connect();
}

export { db };
```